# running linux copy and rename command with java

Tags: java, linux

```
File wd = new File("/bin");
Process proc = null;
try {
    proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/bash", null, wd);
} catch (IOException e) {
    logger.info(e);
    e.printStackTrace();
}
if (proc != null) {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(proc.getOutputStream())), true);
    //out.println("su - root");
    out.println("cp /usr/rock/Masterfile.xls /usr/rock/generatedfile/");
    out.println("mv /usr/rock/generatedfile/Masterfile.xls /usr/rock/generatedfile/userid.xls");

    try {
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            logger.info(line);
        }
        proc.waitFor();
        in.close();
        out.close();
        proc.destroy();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.info(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am trying to copy master file and want to rename according to the userid. Code does not showing any error but i dont see any file in the folder i specify. I tried with sudo root command even its not copying and renaming the file. How should i do in order to run copy and rename command to run successfully from java program.

Comment: Maybe you should run the cp and mv commands through Process, and not put bash in the middle.

Comment: I tried with Process Process myProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd); but still the same.

Comment: Did you flush the output stream to bash?

Comment: flush() not doing anything Its same...

Answer (score 2):

You're not reading from the process's standard error.  So if your `cp` and `mv` commands are reporting errors, you won't be seeing them.

It's possible to read from the process's standard error, but that's complicated if you're using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` because reading from standard error needs to be done in a separate thread to reading from standard output.

Java 5 introduced a new class for running external processes: [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).  In my opinion, the single biggest advantage of a ProcessBuilder is that you can redirect the standard error of the process into its standard output.  That leaves you with only one stream to read from, and hence no need for a separate thread.

I would recommend replacing your use of `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)` with the following:

```
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash");
    builder.directory(wd);
    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    proc = builder.start();
```

If the files aren't being copied, then chances are that `cp` and `mv` are reporting errors.  Making this change should hopefully allow you to see the errors being reported.

Comment: 02-03-2012 15:24:12 [http-8080-11]  INFO UtilServices:119 - cp: cannot create                                         
regular file `/usr/yash/cool/flash/MainTemplate.xls': Permission denied                                                 
  02-03-2012 15:24:12 [http-8080-11]  INFO UtilServices:119 - mv: cannot stat `/                                        
usr/yash/cool/flash/MainTemplate.xls': No such file or directory                                                                     I am getting above error. Permission denied. How to give permission?

Comment: @user451872: I'd guess that the user that you're running your Java code as doesn't have permission to create a file in the `flash` directory, or perhaps doesn't have read access to any of the directories in the path.  With no access to your machine, I can't really tell.  Can you try `su`ing to that user and running the `cp` and `mv` commands?

Comment: @user451872: running `cp` and `mv` as root???? Are you seriously kidding me?  Completely unnecessary use of `root` such as this is a recipe for utter pwnage, and I'm certainly not going to help you with that.  Besides, have you never heard of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege ?

Comment: I got the error  "su: must be run from a terminal." how to run su command.

Comment: @user451872: you can't run `su` except from a terminal, and that's for a very good reason: security.  I cannot recommend strongly enough that you stop trying to run your `cp` and `mv` commands as `root`.

Comment: What u suggest for copy and renaming the file from java